# HTML Validation message not showing

Tags: jquery, validation, model-view-controller

I have a form and am using jquery to pop up a spinner before the form is submitted if it passes validation.  This works.  Only issue is that the validation message does not appear when form does not pass validation.  Message will appear if I just use a submit button.  Any ideas on what I'm missing?

Update - I added the Property below with the Data Annotations.  Correction - form works with submit skipping the jquery but also with @required="required" as shown.  If I remove that the Data Annotation doesn't seem to work - the "required" attribute does not show in the html.  All the document I can find for this is for MVC.Core - which I am not using - so maybe that's my issue

Form

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("", ", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form", id="membername" }))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Person.Salutation, new { @class = "form-control", required = "required" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Person.Salutation, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
<input id="savememberbutton" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn btn-success" value="Save"/>
 }

$('#savememberbutton').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var thisform = $(this).closest("form");
    var ok = $(thisform)[0].checkValidity();
    if (ok) {
        $('#spinnerModal').modal('show'); 
        $(thisform).submit(); 
    }
});

    [StringLength(5)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Dr/Rev/")]
    public string Salutation { get; set; }
```

Comment: your script  looks like ok. Only one thing is missing is `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Person.Salutation, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })` right under the `@Html.TextBoxFor` . Ofcourse its only work if you use **required**  as ** data annotation**  in your model.

Comment: I'll try that - thanks - I have [Required in the Data Annotation and it does prevent submit on invalid but doesn't show the message. it does however show a message if I use a submit input and skip the jquery code.

Comment: see update above

Comment: did you include `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Person.Salutation, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })` ,this ?

Comment: @ZiaulKabirFahad - yes - forgot to show that in update

Comment: this seem okay and its work for me. however you could try with this   `$.validator.setDefaults({ignore: []});` in your script right before your form submit function.

Comment: thanks @ZiaulKabirFahad - will try that in a bit